# convert multiple unorder lists in single unorder list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi help me as i am new .. i have multiple ULs in a div with class multiple .. how to get all the ULs and convert it into single UL in another div with class single  ?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="multiple">
                <ul class="menu1">
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="menu2">
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find It</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
<div class="single"> </div>
```

Comment: Looks like basic jQuery selectors and .append would do the trick. Google basic jQuery tutorials to find out how to apply these.

Comment: `$('.multiple ul li').appendTo($('<ul/>').appendTo('.single'));` ???  http://jsfiddle.net/9hu6fsh7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.multiple > ul > li').detach().appendTo($('.single > ul'));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d05pLe06/)